# How to modify this code to print equivalents?

Tags: python

I will keep it simple. I need to modify my code so that it will compute and print a table of celsius temperatures and the Fahrenheit equivalents every 10 degrees from 0C to 100C

Here is what I have.

```
# convert.py
# A program to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit

def main():
    celsius = eval(input("What is the Celsius temperature? "))
    fahrenheit = 9/5 * celsius + 32
    print ("The temperature is", farenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit.")
```

Comment: Don't use **`eval()`**.

Comment: Well that is what I have at the moment, it works fine to convert user input but I need to fix it to do a different task. I am stuck in the loop to print every 10c with the equivalent. As a side note this is my second day of programming. :)

Comment: `for x in range(0, 101, 10): print(f'Celcius: {x}, Fahrenheit:{x * 9/5 + 32}')`

Comment: @NewProgrammer, don't take it lightly. See the dangerous behaviour of using `eval`: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Thanks. I will try this method. I appreciate it.

Comment: You seem to know how to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop, range and a formatting string:

```py
for celcius in range(0, 101, 10):
    print(f'Celcius: {celcius}, Fahrenheit: {celcius * 9 / 5 + 32}')
```

Range explanation: `range(0, 101, 10)` will start at 0, finish at 100 (101 is excluded) and have jumps of 10 between each element. If you want to investigate more into range, you can cast list to it and have a representation of what happens like this:

```py
>>> list(range(0, 101, 10))
>>> [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

So celcius will take those values in the iterations of `for celcius in range(0, 101, 10)`

Then all what's left to do is to print the value of celcius and fehrenheit. Using the format string (`f''`) You have: `f'Celcius: {celcius}, Fahrenheit: {celcius * 9 / 5 + 32}'`, the formatter will evaluate what's in the curly brackets (`{}`) and build the string with the result of what's in between.

Comment: You know, one thing is beyond me is how the mind of programmers work. Learning on my own to program will be a challenge for sure but I am so excited about it specially when there are people like you with the knowledge and the heart to help people like me. I am thankful.